# Using distributive law

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it allowed to use distributive laws like this?

$$
 \{(A^c \cap B^c)  \ \cup \ (A \ \cap B)\} \to \{(A^c \cup(A \cap B)\} \cap \{B^c \cup (A \cap B)\}
$$

I thought to use this law there should be 3 different sets not 4.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid rule for sets. But what does the $\{A \}$ notation mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is unnecessarily complicated, so that might be why it's tricky to untangle. Note that you're doing nothing with the intersection $A \cap B$, so just replace it with $C$. Also, you aren't doing anything DeMorgan-like with complements, so replace $A^c$ with $A$, and $B^c$ with $B$. Then we have $(A \cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$.